# jquery multiple slides play/stop button

Tags: jquery

Hi I am calling slide show multiple time like this

```
 $('.content-slide').myelinSlider({
                     auto : false,
                     type : 'content',
                     speed : 1500
                 });

 $('.content-slide-temperature').myelinSlider({
             auto : false,
             type : 'content',
             speed : 1500
         });
```

My problem is how do I set parameter of 'content-slide auto' to true by clicking play/stop button.
I tried like this but confuse

```
 <span id="content-slide_play>Play</span>
 <span id="content-slide-temperature_play>Play</span>

$('#content-slide_play').click(function(){                  
    $(this).toggleClass('#content-slide_stop');
});
```

thank you for your any suggestons

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you want to do? It's not clear.

Comment: I just want to change the value of auto parameter to true after clicking the Play button like auto:false to auto:true just to auto play the slide thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just update the plugin options on click:

```
$('#content-slide_play').click(function(){                  
    $('.content-slide').myelinSlider({
        auto : true,
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it is working. how can i check these current values like content-slide.myelinSlider.auto=?